# How can one obtain all calibration data which is needed to plot error_map of the ibm backend from few month ago?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, noise

I want to plot the error map of an IBM Quantum backend from the calibration data I saved a month ago. The saved file just contain qubit properties and to plot error map I would need all information including gate error ( as in csv file when download calibration data from the backend). I used `prop_2023 = backend.properties(datetime=dt)` to get backend properties of that specific time and use this command to read `prop_2023.to_dict()` but still I don't know how to extract the information I needed to plot error map of the backend! Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply load the calibration data into the corresponding fake backend, then use `plot_error_map` with it as follows:

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakePerth
from qiskit.visualization import plot_error_map
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_perth')

calibrations_time = datetime(year=2022, month=2, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
properties = backend.properties(datetime=calibrations_time)

fake_backend = FakePerth()
fake_backend._props_dict = properties.to_dict() # <== here
plot_error_map(fake_backend)
```

Here, I assumed that your backend is ibm_perth.